# Django CharField To String

Tags: django, django-models, tostring

I'm building a tagging system in Django and would like to allow spaces and other characters in the tag name for display but filter them out and use lower case when matching names etc.

To that end I have added a field to my Tag model as so:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    matchname = re.sub("\W+" , "", name.lower())
```

However I am running into a problem, the CharField is not a string and I cannot for the life of me find out how to convert it to one!

Comment: Argh... can't post an answer without getting a server error :-(

Comment: Have an up-vote instead then! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're defining a `class` there so `name` is not a string it's a [Django Field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#fields).

Additionally, converting `name` to `matchname` at the class level doesn't make any sense.  You should be doing this on the instance.

You could add a method to your class to do this:

```
def get_matchname(self):
    """Returns the match name for a tag"""
    return re.sub("\W+" , "", self.name.lower())
```

Comment: Something like `def matchname(self): return re.sub("\W+" , "", self.name.lower())` (this is what I was going to put in my answer, but today stackoverflow hates me).

Comment: @Dominic - Was just editing the answer to add that.  <meta>I keep getting server error too; the site keeps logging me in and out which I think is the source of the problem.</meta>

Comment: And a documentation link too! :D

Answer (score 4):

First you have to define the field as as a CharField to be able to use it for search.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    matchname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

And then you can overwrite the save function in the model to populate it like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    def save(self):
        self.matchname = re.sub("\W+" , "", self.name.lower())
        super(Tag,self).save()
```

Or use a signal for doing the same:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

def populate_matchname(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.matchname = re.sub("\W+" , "", instance.name.lower())

pre_save(populate_matchname,sender=Tag)
```

Comment: In my case I had to put `*args, **kwargs` as a parameter for `save()` after `self`. Anyways it worked. Thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a method:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def get_matchname(self):
        return re.sub("\W+" , "", name.lower())
```

And use `property` decorator:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    @property
    def matchname(self):
        return re.sub("\W+" , "", name.lower())
```

All this will let you to access `name` field lowercased and with non-word characters stripped. But you won't get it stored in DB. If you want this you'll need to add another `CharField` and keep `name` and `matchname` synchronized.