# Django : TypeError at "?" __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: mysql, django

I tried to make a crud using Django but i got error

```
TypeError at  "?" __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

the model :

```
from django.db import models

class Module(models.Model):
    Module = models.CharField("Module", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField("Created At", auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Module

class Matiere(models.Model):
    Matiere = models.CharField("Matiere", max_length=255, blank = True, null = True)
    ModuleId = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField("Created At", auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Matiere
```

the view error line:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
34              <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1"></div>
35              <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
36                  <form method="post" novalidate>
37                      {% csrf_token %}
38                      {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
39                      {{ hidden_field }}
40                      {% endfor %}
41                      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
42                      <div class="form-group">
43                          {{ field.label_tag }}
44                          {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
45                          {% if field.help_text %}
46                          <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
47                          {% endif %}
48                      </div>
49                      {% endfor %}
50                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">post</button>
51                  </form>
52                  <br>
53              </div>
54              <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1"></div>
```

i don't know how to fix this error ,i searched for error its seems the error in the model exactly in return self the last line but i can't fix the issue , Could you help me please ?

Comment: Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback** please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely that you're returning anything other than a string in yout `__str__` function. I will first suggest you to try to [change your field to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782622/django-charfield-to-string) while returning your fields.

Plus, your error sounds like that you didn't apply your migrations properly, and please double-check on that.

Comment: I figure out the error it was a null data in my Database